# discord.js reset menu on selection

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So currently I'm making a ticket system which runs when a topic is selected via menu. However, the selection can't be undone automatically. Is there any way?
So I mean when I select the Bug topic and after the ticket being created, the select menu don't go back to Please select(The light letters) but I want to make that happen.

-- sorry for my poor english skills

+)

Currently when the menu is selected, we get input via modal and makes the ticket.
So

```js
import Modal, { TextInputComponent } from '../../structures/Modal.js';
import { TextInputStyle } from 'discord-api-types/v9';

export const id = 'ticket-type';

function makeModel(type) {
    return placeholders[type](new Modal()
        .setCustomId('create-ticket')
        .setTitle('티켓 만들기'));
}

const placeholders = {
    report: (modal) => modal.addComponents(
        new TextInputComponent()
            .setCustomId('report')
            .setLabel('신고할 사람의 Minecraft IGN(닉네임)을 작성해주세요.')
            .setPlaceholder('예시: komq')
            .setRequired(true)
            .setMaxLength(16),
        new TextInputComponent()
            .setCustomId('reason')
            .setLabel('위반된 규칙을 써주세요.')
            .setPlaceholder('예시: 핵 사용')
            .setRequired(true)
            .setMaxLength(30),
    ),
    feedback: (modal) => modal.addComponents(new TextInputComponent()
        .setCustomId('feedback')
        .setLabel('해당 서버에게 줄 피드백 내용을 작성해주세요.')
        .setPlaceholder('예시: 이 미니게임에 이런 게 있었다면 좋겠어요.')
        .setRequired(true)
        .setMinLength(5)
        .setMaxLength(500)
        .setStyle(TextInputStyle.Paragraph)),
    bug_report: (modal) => modal.addComponents(new TextInputComponent()
        .setCustomId('bug_report')
        .setLabel('발견한 버그를 써주세요. 영상 등의 첨부 자료가 있으면 더 좋습니다.')
        .setPlaceholder('예시: 이 미니게임에서 특정 행동을 하면 블록이 파괴됩니다.')
        .setRequired(true)
        .setMinLength(5)
        .setMaxLength(500)
        .setStyle(TextInputStyle.Paragraph)),
};

export async function onRun(menu) {
    await makeModel(menu.values[0]).sendToInteraction(menu);
}
```

and after the input,

````js
import { clientId, ticketCategoryId, ticketPingRoleId } from '../../constants/config.js';
import { MessageActionRow, MessageButton, MessageEmbed, Permissions } from 'discord.js';
import getTheme from '../../constants/themes.js';

export const id = 'create-ticket';

export const closeTicketRow = new MessageActionRow()
    .addComponents(
        new MessageButton()
            .setCustomId('close-ticket')
            .setLabel('티켓 닫기')
            .setEmoji('')
            .setStyle('DANGER'),
    );

const types = {
    feedback: '피드백', bug_report: '버그 신고', report: '신고',
};

export async function onRun(ticket) {
    const category = await ticket.guild.channels.fetch(ticketCategoryId);
    const type = Object.keys(types).find((t) => ticket.getValue(t));

    const channel = await category.createChannel(
        '요청 ' + (Math.random() + 1).toString(36).substring(7), {
            type: 'GUILD_TEXT',
            topic: ticket.member.id,
            permissionOverwrites: [
                {
                    id: ticket.guild.roles.everyone.id,
                    deny: [Permissions.FLAGS.VIEW_CHANNEL],
                },
                {
                    id: ticket.member.id,
                    allow: [Permissions.FLAGS.VIEW_CHANNEL],
                },
                {
                    id: clientId,
                    allow: [Permissions.FLAGS.VIEW_CHANNEL],
                },
            ],
        },
    );
    ticket.reply({ content: '티켓을 제작했습니다!', ephemeral: true });
    const embed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor(getTheme('primary'))
        .addField('채널', `<#${channel.id}>`)
        .setAuthor({ name: ticket.member.user.tag, iconURL: ticket.member.user.displayAvatarURL() })
        .setTimestamp()
        .addField('유형', types[type]);
    let send = ticket.getValue(type);
    if (type === 'report') {
        send += '을(를) ' + ticket.getValue('reason') + '(으)로 신고합니다.';
    } else {
        send = '```' + send + '```';
    }

    await channel.send({ embeds: [embed], components: [closeTicketRow] });
    await channel.send(`<@&${ticketPingRoleId}>,\n${send}`);
}
````

I couldn't find any function to set the selected menu to default. So, I would be thankful if you give me the function and where should I run that.

Comment: Could you please share your code/attempt with us, it would greatly assist with us helping you